# No module named numpy but requirements are already satisfied (Anaconda)

Tags: python, numpy, pip, anaconda, conda

I have installed different packages with pip command from terminal in a virtual environment on Anaconda. If I try to run a file.py from terminal I get the error 'No module named 'numpy' while if I run the file.py by using spyder (releted to the same environment) everything works well.

How Could I fix the problem?

pip --verions is:
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\giulia\Anaconda3\envs\reasoning\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

python --version is:
Python 3.6.10 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: How do you run said `file.py`? Most probably you run it with a different Python.

Comment: you are right! this was the problem. I used a different python. Now, it is fine. I have just written "file.py" from terminal. I had to write "python file.py".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Code for edit your python programs, then choose the correct worrkspace clicking on the down left corner, after select your worspace environment and select the anaconda worspace (In my case is named conda) [Python Workspaces in Visual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa0BG.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the new windows update , we need to wait until January for this to resolve.

Read this document , It may be helpful.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html